# Python equivalent of a Perl function-based cgi style

Tags: python, perl, cgi

I was taught to use Perl cgi (CGI(':standard')) like so:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
use CGI qw/:standard/;           # load standard CGI routines
print header,                    # create the HTTP header
      start_html('hello world'), # start the HTML
      h1('hello world'),         # level 1 header
      end_html;                  # end the HTML
```

When moving over to Python, I find I have to do this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
print "Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n"
print '<html>'
print '<head>'
print '<title>Hello Word</title>'
print '</head>'
print '<body>'
print '<h1>Hello Word!</h1>'
print '</body>'
print '</html>'
```

Is a function-based approach to cgi possible with Python as it is in Perl? What major challenges would you anticipate in trying to create such a package (should one not exist)?

Comment: We use Django for our stuff here in python.

Comment: The Perl code you've shown is massively outdated. The CGI module has not in the Perl code for several years, and the HTML generation functions you have used have been removed from the CGI distribution and moved into their own module. [The whole thing is highly discouraged](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jKOqtRMT85s). Regardless of if you want to do Perl or Python, please invest some time to learn a more modern approach. That can be a web framework, but it does not have to be. At least use a template engine, do not mix code and HTML. That is horrible to maintain.

Comment: In this day and age, I would say that using CGI is probably a bad idea, maybe even a terrible idea. Then again, I don't know what you're doing, so maybe not. Using a framework like Django, Pyramid, or Flask is almost certainly a better way to go.

Comment: unrelated: you don't need `'\r\n\r\n'`. In Python, `print` already writes the newline i.e, to writes headers: `print 'Content-type:text/html'; print;` ([CGI header syntax may differ from HTTP header syntax](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3875#section-6.3.4))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a CGI script written in a "function-based" style using [`bottle` Python web framework](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/):

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
from bottle import route, run, template

@route('/hello/<name>')
def index(name):
    return template('<b>Hello {{name}}</b>!', name=name)

run(server='cgi') # transform the application into a valid CGI script
```

To install `bottle` module, run the usual `pip install bottle` or just [download a single `bottle.py` file](https://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/tutorial.html#installation).

To try it, make the script executable:

```py
$ chmod +x cgi-bin/cgi-script
```

Start [development] CGI server in the current directory:

```py
$ python3 -mhttp.server --cgi --bind localhost
```

Open the page:

```py
$ python -mwebbrowser http://localhost:8000/cgi-bin/cgi-script/hello/World
```

Unless you must use CGI, consider other [deployment options](https://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/deployment.html).

Comment: Thank you for the response, it was illuminating. As you've recommended (and since so many people have been pointing me away from it), I'm likely going to ditch the cgi I know and start from scratch. The `bottle` web framework seems as good a place as any to start again.

Comment: @PranayVishwanath: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)